# Reference for asymptotics of $\left(\!1+\frac{x(n)}n\!\right)^{\!n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, reference-request, asymptotics

It is well known that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\! 1+\frac{x}n \!\right)^{\!n}=e^x$ for constant $x$.
When $x$ depends on $n$, things are a little more interesting.

If $x(n)\ll\sqrt{n}$, then $\left(\! 1+\frac{x(n)}n \!\right)^{\!n} \sim e^{x(n)}$.

However, if $\sqrt{n}\ll x(n)\ll n^{2/3}$, then we get a correction factor: $\left(\! 1+\frac{x(n)}n \!\right)^{\!n} \sim e^{-x(n)^2/2n} \,e^{x(n)}$.

And when $n^{2/3}\ll x(n)\ll n^{3/4}$, we get an additional correction factor of $e^{x(n)^3/3n^2}$.

And in general, for $x(n)\ll n$,
$$
\left(\! 1+\frac{x(n)}n \!\right)^{\!n} 
\;\sim\;
\exp\left( \sum_{k=1}^{t} (-1)^{k-1}\frac{x(n)^k}{k\,n^{k-1}} \right),
\quad\text{where}\quad
t=\left\lfloor\frac1{\log_n(n/x(n))}\right\rfloor.$$
All this follows from the fact that
$$
\left(\! 1+\frac{x(n)}n \!\right)^{\!n}
\;=\; 
\exp\left[n \log\left(\! 1+\frac{x(n)}n \!\right)\right]
\;=\;
e^{x(n)} \exp\left(- \frac{x(n)^2}{2 n} + \frac{x(n)^3}{3 n^2} - \ldots \right).
$$

This seems interesting enough to be well-known, but I've not knowingly encountered it anywhere. Does anyone know of a suitable reference?

Comment: Well, the expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ is well-known ("Newton-Mercator expansion"), and this is just a direct application of that.